# Is it possible to add a new Security Policy in .NET without recompiling?

Tags: .net, security, policy-based-security

If I need to add new test to a policy-based security configuration, MS says to add a new condition or the like to my handler or create another handler.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("BadgeEntry", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.HasClaim(c =>
                (c.Type == ClaimTypes.BadgeId ||
                 c.Type == ClaimTypes.TemporaryBadgeId) &&
                 c.Issuer == "https://microsoftsecurity")));
});
```

I am trying to avoid having to recompile everytime I need a new exception or a new policy needs to be added.  That seems to me to be just as tightly coupled as adding a new role to an attribute everytime something new pops up.  Add a new role to my attribute, recompile.

Is it possible to add a new Security Policy in .NET without recompiling?

(I have read this, [Can Policy Based Authorization be more dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247094/can-policy-based-authorization-be-more-dynamic))

Comment: The following link might help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280397/bind-authorizationpolicy-to-controller-action-without-using-authorizeattribute