# MVC6 Resource Based Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following cenario:

-> WebAPi wicth gives me a custom Permission Manager that has methods to check wheter user can access some resource or not.

-> After the login I call that WebAPI and **store** the PermissionManager.

-> On each action I would check using "`[Authorize("ResouceName")]`" against the PermissionManager.

I´ve read a lot of docs, but just can´t figure out how to correct implement this.

**Challanges**:

*What's best way to store the PermissionManager class? Cache?

*I´ve tried out the building it using `IAuthorizationRequirement`. But how to access the Policy name given in the "Autorize("ResourceName")"?

*Would be good not to store the users resources at Claims. Given that this application has a lot of resources and I´m using cookies to persist claims.

Any tips and suggestions would be apreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples

Comment: Check out the documentation on how to implement Policy based authorization http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/dependencyinjection.html or here for an example on how to populate it from DB http://stackoverflow.com/a/36447358/455493

Comment: @Tseng in the stackoverflow awenser you suggest, how to pass the "IUserPermissionsRepository" if that repo comes from a WebAPI just after the user makes his login?

Comment: As long as the repository (or `DbContex` if you don't use repositories) is registered in the ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection container, it will resolve automatically.

Comment: Ok. But in my case the repository comes from another system witch control acess permissions. And it´s sent to me after user make his login. How to solve that? Because I can´t register at DI something that changes after app is runing.