# Custom Authorization Based On Resource - Dynamic Roles - AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

I would like to implement an authorization based on a custom resource code on the new ASP Core for controller classes and methods. Roles on my project are not static.

Something Like:

```
[Authorize(PermissionsEnum.AccessXYZScreen)]
```

And if that Role has that permission grant access. This was quite simple on the previous version.

I have read
[How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/31465227#31465227) and https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html but none of them fit my needs.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/36445780/455493

Comment: That might work quite well, not as simple as I expected but sounds like a plan. Thanks!