# injectiong an instance of ApplicationModel into an MVC service which will itself be a singleton

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to display components of a navigation tree only if a principal has access to those components (whether roles or policy based).

I am not particularly familiar with MVC core, but reading to date would indicate that I could build a list of what authorization filters will be applied to an action with something like:

```
    public NavigationNodePermissionResolver(ApplicationModel appModel)
    {
        foreach (var controllerModel in appModel.Controllers)
        {
            var contextFilters = controllerModel.Filters.OfType<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>().ToList();
            foreach (ActionModel action in controllerModel.Actions)//todo restrain to HttpGet
            {
                var actionFilters = action.Filters.OfType<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>().ToList();
            }
        }
```

How can I inject an instance of the application model into the instantiator for NavigationNodePermissionResolver?

NavigationNodePermissionResolver itself will be injectable as:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<INavigationNodePermissionResolver, NavigationNodePermissionResolver>();
```

**edit**

the follow on to this question - what to do when I have a list of the IAsyncAuthorizationFilters is [in this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023530/test-if-call-to-iasyncauthorizationfilter-onauthorizationasync-has-failed).

as follow up information the ApplicationModel is a property of the ApplicationModelProviderContext which I found out about in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825021/override-global-authorize-filter-in-asp-net-core-mvc-1-0#35863514) - it does seem to be roughly what I am after, but it may be the approach I am using to obtain and then execute authorization filters is completely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I can instantiate and inject the same instance which implements 2 interfaces. I ended up within Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
var customAppModelProvider = new CustomApplicationModelProvider();
services.AddSingleton<IApplicationModelProvider>(customAppModelProvider);
services.AddSingleton<IActionFilterMap>(customAppModelProvider);
```

And the implementation:

```
public interface IActionFilterMap
{
    IEnumerable<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter> GetFilters(string area, string controller, string action);
}
public class CustomApplicationModelProvider : IApplicationModelProvider, IActionFilterMap
{
    //It will be executed after AuthorizationApplicationModelProvider, which has order -990
    public int Order => 0;

    private ReadOnlyDictionary<ActionKey, IEnumerable<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>> _authDictionary;

    public IEnumerable<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter> GetFilters(string area, string controller, string action)
    {
        var key = new ActionKey(area, controller, action);
        if (_authDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out IEnumerable<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter> returnVar))
        {
            return returnVar;
        }
        return null;//returning null rather than Enumerable.Empty so consuming method can detect if action found and has no Authorization, or action not found

    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
        var returnVar = new Dictionary<ActionKey, IEnumerable<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>>();
        foreach (var controllerModel in context.Result.Controllers)
        {
            var controllerFilters = controllerModel.Filters.OfType<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>().ToList();
            string area = controllerModel.Attributes.OfType<AreaAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.RouteValue;
            foreach (ActionModel action in controllerModel.Actions)//todo restrain to get
            {
                var method = action.Attributes.OfType<HttpMethodAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (method == null || method.HttpMethods.Contains("GET"))
                {
                    var key = new ActionKey(area, controllerModel.ControllerName, action.ActionName);
                    if (action.Filters.OfType<AllowAnonymousFilter>().Any())
                    {
                        returnVar.Add(key, Enumerable.Empty<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var filters = controllerFilters.Concat(action.Filters.OfType<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>()).ToArray();
                        returnVar.Add(key, filters);
                    }
                }
            }
            _authDictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<ActionKey, IEnumerable<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter>>(returnVar);
        }
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
        //empty
    }

    private class ActionKey : Tuple<string, string, string>
    {
        public ActionKey(string area, string controller, string action) : base(area ?? string.Empty, controller, action)
        {
            _hashCode = base.GetHashCode();
        }

        int _hashCode;
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```