# test if call to IAsyncAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync has failed

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

This question relates to a larger objective outlined in [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023428/injectiong-an-instance-of-applicationmodel-into-an-mvc-service-which-will-itself). To recap

> I would like to display components of a navigation tree only if a principal has access to those components (whether roles or policy based).

In the previous question I will have a List of the autorization filters which belong to a controller and action. Once I have an instance of the IHttpContextAccessor and therefore the ClaimsPrincipal, how might I test if the principal would pass all the above mentioned list of authorization filters?

That is, if I mocked up something like:

```
var mockAuthFilter = new AuthorizationFilterContext(...);
foreach (IAsyncAuthorizationFilter filter in filterListForGivenAction)
{ 
    await filter.OnAuthorizationAsync(mockAuthFilter);
```

The question is - how might I test if any calls to OnAuthorizationAsync have failed?

Alternatively, would there be a better approach altogether to ensure the navigation tree only displays nodes/leaves for which the principal is authorized to view based on the AuthorizeAttribute (policy and/or roles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was written there if I had looked closely enough at the annotations on the properties of AuthorizationFilterContext -

> [Result] - Setting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext.Result to a non-null value inside an authorization filter will short-circuit the remainder of the filter pipeline.

Therefore The method ends up being:

```
private async Task<bool> IsValid(IEnumerable<IAsyncAuthorizationFilter> filters, ActionContext actionContext)
{
    var context = new AuthorizationFilterContext(actionContext, filters.Cast<IFilterMetadata>().ToList());
    foreach (var f in filters)
    {
        await f.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
        if (context.Result != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question (often people don't do that). I was looking for the same information.