# Allow "semi anonymous" authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openiddict

I have a case where I need some controller methods to be accessible either by an authenticated user, or if the request contains a sort of "acccess token" in the url.

For example:

Either an authenticated user could make a call to:
`https://example.com/some/resource`

Or a non authenticated user could make the same call, but add some kind of token to the url (or as a header):
`https://example.com/some/resource?token=123abc`

The token does not have to be super secret, only something hard to guess.

```
[AllowSpecialToken]
[HttpGet]
[Route("some/resource")]
public async Task<string> GetSomeResource()
{
    return "some resource";
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how to write the `AllowSpecialTokenAttribute`. And how to get that to run before the authentication (using `OpenIddict`) we have in place now.

Is this a stupid use case? Should I find another solution?

To give some context: We have a SPA that calls our API. Some pages of the SPA can be shared with others (non user) just by sending a link. That link will contain the token. The content of those pages are not critical security wise, but they shouldn't be completely open.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own authentication attribute. I've done something like that in the past, here is my stub at it:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // this will read `token` parameter from your URL
        ValueProviderResult valueProvided = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("token");
        if (valueProvided == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }

        var providedToken = valueProvided.AttemptedValue;

        var storedToken = "12345"; // <-- get your token value from DB or something

        if (storedToken != providedToken)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then decorate your action with the attribute:

```
[TokenAuthentication]
[HttpGet]
[Route("some/resource")]
public async Task<string> GetSomeResource()
{
    return "some resource";
}
```

And get your URI looking like `https:\\www.example.com\api\some\resource?token=12345`

Comment: Is this for Asp.Net Core or Asp.Net?

Comment: That's for old asp. Apologies, I've missed that you tagged the question as Core

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Guess I fooled you with the asp.net-identity tag. Removed  that :) Do have any idea on how to do it using asp.net core?

Comment: Sorry, not had a chance to do the same in Core. I can only imagine the technique would be described in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below and see if it works for you. 
**Caveat**: I have absolutely no idea if this is the "correct" way to do this. I just know it is a way that appears to work. Please test and downvote if you find problems. I still have an open [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274464/configure-authentication-to-return-a-401-unauthorized-for-some-actions) on another authentication handler I have written, but with no replies, so use with caution. It may be worth contacting blowdart (search users) at MS if you are going to pursue this use case.

**Middleware Class**

```
public class TokenCodeAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public const string DefaultSchemeName = "TokenAuthScheme";

    public TokenCodeAuthHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, 
        UrlEncoder encoder, 
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        AuthenticateResult result = await this.Context.AuthenticateAsync();
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //User has supplied details
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(result.Ticket);
        }
        else if (Context.Request.Query["token"] == "123abc")   //TODO: Change hard-coded token
        {
            //User has supplied token
            string username = "Test";    //Get/set username here
            var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username, ClaimValueTypes.String, Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username, ClaimValueTypes.String, Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                };

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name));
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

**Configure Services in Startup**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TokenCodeAuthHandler>(
        TokenCodeAuthHandler.DefaultSchemeName, 
        (o) => { });
```

**Attribute Usage**

Use on controller actions as follows: 
*Note - I couldn't seem to override controller level authorize attributes).*

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = TokenCodeAuthHandler.DefaultSchemeName)]
[HttpGet]
[Route("some/resource")]
public async Task<string> GetSomeResource()
{
    return "some resource";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I can't get it to work :/ . My "regular" authentication kicks in before the TokenCodeAuthHandler is even called...

Comment: I couldn't seem to get it to override controller level `[Authorize]` tags, so on the controllers I tested it on, I had to remove controller level tags and just have the appropriate Auth tag on each action. Maybe someone will come up with a better way.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't have it on each controller, but a global [Authorize] for everything.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could use a [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x#selecting-the-scheme-with-policies) to select the scheme. Otherwise, this probably isn't the answer you are looking for :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! However, this still does not work when I want this to override a global auth-filter configured like `services                .AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                })`

Comment: OK, I see the problem. Have rolled back last edit. Only link I could find that is relevant is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825021/override-global-authorize-filter-in-asp-net-core-mvc-1-0#35863514) which applies to Core 1.0. Seems like a lot of effort just to override a global filter though.